# 'undefined' error when accessing JSON data element in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I have a couple of nested v-fors that display some JSON data in a three-level parent-child relationship. When I try to display the grandchild info, I get this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'threadId')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'threadId')
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/PageHome.vue?vue&type=template&id=c0c75584:57:318)
at renderList (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2594:16)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/PageHome.vue?vue&type=template&id=c0c75584:49:450)
at renderList (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2594:16)
at Proxy.render (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/PageHome.vue?vue&type=template&id=c0c75584:45:343)
at renderComponentRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:887:38)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5064:46)
at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:216:19)
at instance.update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5161:51)
at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5169:5)
```

For reference, here's the structure of the data:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "forums": [
        "-KpOx5Y4AqRr3sB4Ybwj",
        "-KsjO4_W3W9Q2Z2UmuPr"
      ],
      "name": "Feedback & Information",
      "slug": "feedback-and-information",
      "id": "-KpR7vRkiRPpbUd_TVAR"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "forums": [
    {
      "categoryId": "-KpR7vRkiRPpbUd_TVAR",
      "description": "Important announcements about the forum.",
      "lastPostId": "-KxxU6bYWl-6Xnu9g-56",
      "name": "Announcements",
      "slug": "announcements",
      "threads": [
        "-KvgjI6bfbWYlbYV5ndr"
      ],
      "id": "-KpOx5Y4AqRr3sB4Ybwj"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "threads": [
    {
      "contributors": [
        "FsCDAk9w8NeXEceLV87arpsXjnQ2",
        "L664y3qZSubDbT1R6npC0EEybJ73",
        "VXjpr2WHa8Ux4Bnggym8QFLdv5C3"
      ],
      "firstPostId": "-KsjWehQ--apjDBwSBCZ",
      "forumId": "-KsjPat5MWCx-dkjNVg8",
      "lastPostAt": 1594040497,
      "lastPostId": "-KsjnAAjzfpznUVh4DSa",
      "posts": [
        "-KsjWehQ--apjDBwSBCZ",
        "-KsjefUiIuNkJieBc5Rq",
        "-KsjfvciJhJnebrL4Iw7",
        "-KsjnAAjzfpznUVh4DSa"
      ],
      "publishedAt": 1594035908,
      "slug": "what-kind-of-pet-do-you-have",
      "title": "What kind of pet do you have?",
      "userId": "ALXhxjwgY9PinwNGHpfai6OWyDu2",
      "id": "-KsjWehQ--apjDBwSBCY"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "posts": [
    {
      "edited": {
        "at": 1594037546,
        "by": "ALXhxjwgY9PinwNGHpfai6OWyDu2",
        "moderated": false
      },
      "publishedAt": 1594035908,
      "text": "I'm curious to know what kind...",
      "threadId": "-KsjWehQ--apjDBwSBCY",
      "userId": "ALXhxjwgY9PinwNGHpfai6OWyDu2",
      "id": "-KsjWehQ--apjDBwSBCZ"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "avatar": "https://...",
      "email": "email@gmail.com",
      "lastVisitAt": 1594772078,
      "name": "Chris Fritz",
      "isModerator": true,
      "registeredAt": 1594632260,
      "username": "chrisvfritz",
      "usernameLower": "chrisvfritz",
      "id": "38St7Q8Zi2N1SPa5ahzssq9kbyp1"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And finally, the Vue code:

```
\<template\>
\<div class="col-full"\>
\<div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" class="forum-list"\>

            <h2 class="list-title">
                <a href="category.html">{{ category.name }}</a>
            </h2>
            <div v-for="forumId in category.forums" :key="forumId" class="forum-listing">
                <div class="forum-details">
                    <a class="text-xlarge" href="forum.html">{{ forumById(forumId).name }}</a>
                    <p>{{ forumById(forumId).description }}</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="threads-count">
                    <p><span class="count">{{ 7 }}</span> thread</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="last-thread">
                    <img class="avatar" :src=postById(forumById(forumId).lastPostId).avatar alt="">
                    <div class="last-thread-details">
                        <a href="thread.html">{{ threadById(postById(forumById(forumId).lastPostId).threadId).title }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

\</template\>

\<script setup\>
import sourceData from '@/data.json'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const categories = ref(sourceData.categories)
const forums = ref(sourceData.forums)
const threads = ref(sourceData.threads)
const posts = ref(sourceData.posts)
const users = ref(sourceData.users)

function forumById(forumId) {
return forums.value.find(f =\> f.id === forumId)
}

function threadById(threadId) {
return threads.value.find(t =\> t.id === threadId)
}

function postById(postId) {
return posts.value.find(p =\> p.id === postId)
}

function userById(userId) {
return users.value.find(u =\> u.id === userId)
}

\</script\>

\<style\>\</style\>
```

From the error and the behavior of the app when I change the code, it's bombing on line 21 of the Vue code. It's as if it can't resolve the `threadId` of the post returned by `postById(forumById(forumId).lastPostId)` because that function doesn't return a post. Oddly enough, though, if I wrap this code in a ternary statement like this:

```
{{ if (postById(forumById(forumId).lastPostId)) ? threadById(postById(forumById(forumId).lastPostId).threadId).title : "oops" }}
```

Then everything displays fine, it seems as if the object retuned by `postById()` resolves.

Comment: When `Array.find` fails it returns undefined, and you have a "properties of undefined" error...  Seems it would be prudent to console.log the values being sent to and (especially) from these different methods to determine which data object is causing the error, allowing you to examine the object and figure out why it's erroring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @yoduh. I don't think my question was clear enough. The array _is_ undefined when I access it directly like `forumById(forumId).threads.length` but it resolves if I wrap the same exact code in a ternary statement like `forumById(forumId).threads ? forumById(forumId).threads.length : 0`. This latter code will actually return the length of the threads array.

Comment: Without a runnable example with your data it's hard to believe.  I would posit that the value being returned is simply 0 (or "oops" as in your original question) for one of your loops of the v-for.  The thing about a v-for is that a single error in one loop will crash the whole thing.  The ternary resolves the "false" result for one of your loops while all the others return true so everything works.  It just sounds like you're masking the error that occurs in one bad loop.  I still think you should remove the ternary and add some console.logs to find what data is coming back undefined.